# select data source on the same spagobi report in run time

Tags: switch-statement, report, datasource, spagobi

I have many data sources on spagobi because there are many data bases (PostgreSQL) with a same schema but with diferent data, is it possible choise a particular data source on a same spagobi report in run time?

Comment: What's the technical question here? Either you're asking a product related question, which postgres experts can't answer... or you're asking very generic questions that no one would be able to answer. Please clarify what have you tried, and what issues do you seek help on.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to formulate the technical question better: I have many data sources on spagobi because there are many data bases (PostgreSQL) with a same schema but with diferent data, is possible choise the data sources on a same spagobi report in run time?

Comment: Thnx. Guess I'll let an Spogobi expert answer that one.